# Atomic Float в Go

Tags: многопоточность, golang

Почему в стандартной библиотеке Go, в пакете `sync/atomic` отсутствуют операции для `float`?

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20986159/1892060) интересный ответ с англоязычного СО. Вкратце, сложно, медленно, да и нафиг никому не нужно.

Comment: @Ainar-G Нафиг никому не нужно? Странно...